# Rails i18n - Possible to specify format for specific message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have an entry in my locales.en.yml for a carrierwave whitelist that looks like this:

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
    messages: 
      extension_white_list_error: "You are not allowed to upload %{extension} files, prohibited types: %{prohibited_types}"
```

The way it is the error message reads without the attribute because of the `format: "%{message}"`.

> You are not allowed to upload %{extension} files, prohibited types: %{prohibited_types}

However now all other errors do not show attribute so for example with name field I am getting

> can't be blank

instead of

> Name can't be blank

Is there a way that I can apply the `format: "%{message}"` line ONLY to this specific (`extension_white_list_error`) error message?

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what your actual question is.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I revised my question.  Make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible since Rails 6.

First you have to set this configuration in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_model.i18n_customize_full_message = true
```

Then you can define the format in the model level:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          format: "%{message}"
```

Or in the attribute level (your case):

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              format: "%{message}"
```